# linked list thing warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type

Tags: c, incomplete-type

I have a linked list sort of structure with the skeleton code shown below. However when I compile the code I get "warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type" for the operation temp = temp-> next. I'm just wondering why and if that should be something to worry about. Thanks in advance!

```
typedef struct data {
    size_t size;
    struct data_t* next;
} data_t;

void* dmalloc(size_t numbytes) {
    while(temp!=NULL){
        if(temp->size>=numbytes) {
            //do something
        }
    temp = temp->next; //problem line
    }
return NULL;
}
```

Comment: What does your `temp` declaration look like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use the typedef before it's created. Change your struct to:

```
typedef struct data {
    size_t size;
    struct data* next;
} data_t;
```

Comment: @user1970979 - Not sure why you think you should feel dumb.

Comment: That's not exactly the reason for the error though. The error occurred because the `next` member of the structure has the wrong type:`struct data_t *` (an incomplete type) instead of `struct data *`